# Controlling volume of embed tag on IE

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I need to play a WAV file on an HTML page. IE doesn't support WAV files with the HTML5 audio tag, so especially for that case I am using the embed tag:

```
<EMBED id="audioPlayer" type="audio/wav" src="xx.wav" loop=false>
```

I have managed to play, pause, and stop the audio as well as seek it using javascript, for example:

```
document.getElementById("audioPlayer").currentposition = 0;
```

I want to control the player volume, and fail to find any reference as to how it can be controlled. I have tried setting volume property, and it did not have any affect.

How can I control the volume using javascript?

Comment: "IE doesn't support WAV files with the HTML5 audio tag" -- it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping this will help others, since I could not find any help on this..

I finally solved this issue by using the object tag instead of embed. 
Using the object tag I could access the volume and mute properties.

```
<object type="audio/wav" id="audioPlayer" class="origPlayer" >
    <param name="src" value="put the audio URL here">
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

`audio/wav` is not the correct MIME type for `.wav` files: `audio/x-wav` is.

This MIME type mismatch is probably the reason it isn't playing with `<audio>`.

Try setting the correct MIME type on your `<audio>` tag and it should work.

Failing that, convert the file to MP3. Not only will it increase browser support, but it will result in a smaller file.

Comment: wav is not supported by IE using the audio tag. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats.

Comment: Converting the wav to mp3 is not an option.